# yield to an anonymous block two functions up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

there is probably a simple way to do this.

I'm trying to refactor something like the following

```
def foo(baz)
    baz.update_first
    if baz.has_condition?
       yield baz.val if block_given?
       baz.a
    else
       baz.b
    end
end
```

called like

```
foo(baz) {|b| b.modify}
```

to something like

```
 def foo(baz)
    baz.update_first
    bar(baz)  {|i| yield i if block_given? }        
 end

 def bar(baz)
     if baz.has_condition?
       yield baz.val if block_given?
       baz.a
    else
       baz.b
    end
 end
```

Will that work? How?

I think it will, but I'd appreciate a clear explanation of how yielding inside a block works... reading through proc.c and vm.c and a [relevant git commit in the ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/0a71db8a7497df37b984ea97abfce6b6ffd82df3) , I think when bar is called in foo it executes until it yields, and then you walk up the frame stack to the local environment pointer for block defined in foo, which is called, where the yield walks up to the block foo is called with, executes it, and then you are back in bar.  Is that correct?  Is there a better way to do this?

This feels a little weird to me, like inverting control, and it requires foo to know about baz more then I'd like, but I unfortunately can't simply pass a proc or lambda in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe the concept of `yield` will be more clear if you look at an alternative syntax, which is converting the bloc to a proc argument.

For example, the following examples are the same

```
def my_each(arr)
  arr.each { |x| yield x }
end

def my_each(arr, &blk)
  arr.each { |x| blk.call(x) }
end

# Both are called the same way
my_each([1,2,3]) { |x| print x }
# => 123
```

When using `yield`, the variable is available in the method without declaring it in the parameters list. Prepending an `&` sign to a parameter converts it to a proc, so in the method it can be run with `.call`.

Here's an example of providing a block to one method then executing it two scopes in:

```
def method_a(number, &blk)
  method_b do
    method_c do
      blk.call(number)
    end
  end
end

def method_b(&blk)
  blk.call
end

def method_c(&blk)
  blk.call
end

method_a(1) { |num| puts num + 1 }
# => 2
```

Note that `blk` is not a magic word - you can name the variable whatever you want.

Here's the same thing with yield:

```
def method_a(number)
  method_b do
    method_c do
      yield number
    end
  end
end

def method_b
  yield
end

def method_c
  yield
end

method_a(1) { |num| puts num + 1 }
# => 2
```

I think using the `&blk` syntax is clearer because it assigns a variable to the proc. Just because a proc is used in the method doesn't mean you have to ever run `Proc.new`. The block is automatically converted to a proc.